Catching CompletionException from kotlin function
My ultimate goal is to find the number of partitions for a Pulsar topic (Getting number of partitions of a Pulsar topic: could not be parsed into a proper Uri, missing scheme) but in the process of an alternative method, encountered something peculiar.
I have a hack where I loop up through the max number of partitions and keep trying to create a reader until an error happens.
        for (i in 0..MAX_NUM_PARTITIONS) {
            val topicPartition = "$topic-partition-$i"
            var partitionReader: Reader<ByteArray>? = null
            try {
                partitionReader =
                    client
                        .newReader(BYTES)
                        .startMessageId(MessageId.latest)
                        .topic(topicPartition)
                        .create()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // TODO: This still prints a CompletionException error to the console unnecessarily.
                // Either catch that or calculate # partitions in a cleaner way.
                break
            }

            if (partitionReader != null) {
                readers.add(partitionReader)
            }
        }


java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException$NotAllowedException:
{"errorMsg":"Illegal topic partition name ...

I would like to catch the exception above and not have it print to the console. Despite the try-catch above, it still prints. Why? Is this a Kotlin coroutine related phenomenon? The code does run in a suspend function.
Update: More of the error message: https://pastebin.com/NqMDU5vR
It's specifically the long stacktrace of the CompletionException I don't want to print. The point is to have a better console debug output experience.
The error perhaps is thrown from the Pulsar API internally and there isn't a way to stop that from printing?

just to confirm, the line in the stacktrace is the exact line of the partitionReader assignment, and not where you check for null and add it to the reader?

Yes, I added more of the error message. It doesn't actually point to a particular line but I know it is from the partitionReader = client... line.
